# VBA to create, edit and name multiple queries

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have a workbook with 147 tables across different worksheets (most worksheets have multiple tables and new tables are added regularly).

I need to

1. create connection-only queries for each of the tables,
2. edit them (Remove all Columns except two, transpose the remaining two columns and then turn the first row into Column headers) and
3. name them in a particular pattern e.g. ConnectionTable1 and so on.

This process needs to be followed for each new table added to the workbook.

I would like to automate this using VBA. So far I have the following code (found from searching on the web) which creates connection-only queries for all of the tables in the workbook and adds the data to the Data Model.

**Code:**

```
Sub CreateConnectionToAllTables()
‘Creates Connection Only Queries to all tables in the active workbook.

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lo As ListObject
Dim sName As String
Dim sFormula As String
Dim wq As WorkbookQuery
Dim bExists As Boolean
Dim vbAnswer As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim vbDataModel As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim i As Long
Dim dStart As Double
Dim dTime As Double

‘Display message box to prompt user to run the macro
vbAnswer = MsgBox(“Do you want to run the macro to create connections for all Tables in this workbook?”, vbYesNo, “Power Query Connect All Tables Macro”)

If vbAnswer = vbYes Then

‘Prompt user for Data Model option
vbDataModel = MsgBox(“Do you want to add the data to the Data Model?”, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, “Power Query Connect All Tables Macro”)

‘Set variables
dStart = Timer
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

‘Loop sheets and tables
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
For Each lo In ws.ListObjects

sName = lo.Name
sFormula = “Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=””” & sName & “””]}[Content]”

‘Check if query exists
bExists = False
For Each wq In wb.Queries
If InStr(1, wq.Formula, sFormula) > 0 Then
bExists = True
End If
Next wq

‘Add query if it does not exist
If bExists = False Then

‘Add query
wb.Queries.Add Name:=sName, _
Formula:=”let” & Chr(13) & “” & Chr(10) & ” Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=””” & sName & “””]}[Content]” & Chr(13) & “” & Chr(10) & “in” & Chr(13) & “” & Chr(10) & ” Source”

‘Add to Data Model
If vbDataModel = vbYes Then
wb.Connections.Add2 Name:=”Query – ” & sName, _
Description:=”Connection to the ‘” & sName & “‘ query in the workbook.”, _
ConnectionString:=”OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=” & sName & “;Extended Properties=”, _
CommandText:=”” & sName & “”, _
lCmdtype:=6, _
CreateModelConnection:=True, _
ImportRelationships:=False
‘Add connection only
Else
wb.Connections.Add2 Name:=”Query – ” & sName, _
Description:=”Connection to the ‘” & sName & “‘ query in the workbook.”, _
ConnectionString:=”OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=” & sName & “;Extended Properties=”””””, _
CommandText:=”SELECT * FROM [” & sName & “]”, _
lCmdtype:=2, _
CreateModelConnection:=False, _
ImportRelationships:=False
End If

‘Count connections
i = i + 1

End If
Next lo
Next ws

‘Calc run time
dTime = Timer – dStart

MsgBox i & ” connections have been created in ” & Format(dTime, “0.0”) & ” seconds.”, vbOKOnly, “Process Complete”

End If

End Sub
```

The above code works fine. But I need help modifying it to perform steps (2) editing the queries and (3) naming them in a particular pattern slightly different from the name of the table they are connected to.

Disclaimer: I am very new to this and would appreciate any help with this problem.

**Example:**

Source Tables:
[image: Source Tables:]

Result Table:
[image: Result Table:]

Comment: What do you do with all those connections? If you want to merge all those tables there is much more elegant and efficient way.

Comment: @MichalPalko Yes, once all those connections are established, a new Query appending all those connections loads data to a table. I'm open to a more elegant and efficient way of doing this, if it's possible.

Comment: Added Pictures to the question of examples of source Tables and the resulting Table from the last Query appending all the connection-only queries.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you combine all tables in workbook:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook()
   ,Expand = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Content", {"Info T", "Info"}, {"Info T", "Info"})
in
    Expand
```

[image]

Then you just do additional transformation that you need (probably pivot column).